# How to use in vba unicode characters

Tags: vba, unicode

Having trouble with vba editor. Have looked to many resources, and tried many proper unicodes for letter schwab "ə" and without dot "ı" but non of them displays correctly this letters. Tried to change font shrifts but it gives an error with russian letters. So I need both them displayed on editor as path and there is no way to change the path of folder.
I even tried character wide in vba of u+01DD, u+0259 like &H259,1DD but the result is or question mark or different character.
u+0131 gives an exact i with dot, not what I need.
Anyone knows how to display these characters in vba?

```
FolderName = "C...ə(?)lsheth/folders/"
FileName =Dir(FolderName & "*.xls*")
Do While FileName <> ""
Debug.Print FileName
FileName = Dir()
Loop
```

gives an error 52, Bad name or number
I think problems  lay here that, there are many versions of schwa latin letter, and I need to use(try) all of them as I think the solution must be one of them. Does anyone know how to convert them to use in chrW() for VBA?
List is here; I have taken it from unicode page
0259 ə LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA •  mid-central unrounded vowel •  uppercase is  018F  Ə •  variant uppercase form  018E  Ǝ   is associated with  01DD  ǝ → 01DD ǝ   latin small letter turned e → 04D9 ә   cyrillic small letter schwa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Toddleson, the Visual Basic Editor doesn't support Unicode characters.  And the Dir function doesn't support it either.  However, the FileSystemObject object does support it.

Here's an example that uses the ChrW function to return the desired unicode character, and then uses the FileSystembObject object to loop through each file within the specified folder, filter for .xls files, opens the file, and then saves and closes it.

```
Sub test()

    Dim folderName As String
    folderName = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\D" & ChrW(&H259) & "nmark\" 'change the path accordingly

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim folder As Object
    Set folder = fso.getfolder(folderName)
    
    Dim file As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If InStr(1, file.Name, ".xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
            'etc
            '
            '
            With wb
                .Save
                .Close
            End With
        End If
    Next file
    
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: the same bad name result.

Comment: Maybe I need to try with shell command

Comment: Prior to posting my code, I made sure that the folder name contained the Unicode character "ə", and then I made sure that the file name of a workbook within the folder also contained a Unicode character.  Then I ran the code, and it ran successfully.  Which line is giving you that error?

Comment: fso.getfolder(Foldernme) -> '76' path not found

Comment: So in fact you're getting a "path not found", not a "bad file name".  So you'll need to make sure that your path is correct, and of course you'll need to make sure that any Unicode characters are specified correctly using the ChrW function.

Comment: As a conclusion, when string is inside DIR function, it gives bad pathname error. when in filescriptingobject the error is path not found...Will using shell.execute help any ideas?

Comment: If the path and Unicode characters are specified correctly so that there are no spelling mistakes and no extra spaces anywhere within the filename, the FileSystemObject should work just fine.  As I mentioned, I tested it, and it worked fine.

Comment: The ShellExecute function does not appear to support Unicde characters.

Comment: Are you still having problems?  If so, can you post the exact path that you're using?

Comment: As it is on server path, I cannot post it here. I tried also taking the path of file in that directory then trying to open it, unsuccessful. But the error was there different one, maybe file has been removed or deleted. I took the exact path via copying, then ThisWorkbook.Path, even pasted on cell because in excel the path is written w/out ? mark. All triyng were unsucceful

Comment: Can it be due to font shrift is different in VBE editor ( I have changed it) and the actual "ə" character in windows path? Possibly it is Arial by default. Let me examine also this

Answer (score 1):

`ChrW(399)` = Ə

`ChrW(305)` = ı

These will not be displayed in VBE but when you assign the value into a cell, Excel will display these characters.

Alternatives:

`ChrW(601)` = ə

`ChrW(618)` = ɪ (it looks like the dotless i when printed in Calibri in Excel)

Comment: Thanks, I will try them. I also learnt that with DIR function I can take any path name and use it with asterisk or question mark, and it will give the exact path. I will go on with solutions. Thanks

Comment: I am not displaying them, but using as path name to get files from folder

Comment: @xlmaster If you know exactly which symbols are in the file names then you can use `ChrW` when creating the filepath. But it may be difficult to get exactly the right characters. It will probably be easier to use wildcards like `?` and `*` with `Dir` or to use the `Like` operator and compare all file names to a pattern to get a match.

Comment: Sorry but with both chr wides inside string(these characters are pathnames) and with dir() it gives same error"52". Bad character name. I even used fileSystemObject but seems cannot bypass this unicode issue

Comment: where have you taken the ChrW(601) , I need to convert other encodings of Latin Schwa small letters like ; 0259, 018F,01DD